# how to customize active admin views in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker, activeadmin, datefield

I have active admin in my rails application.

Currently, the `date of birth` field, is having the dropdowns of year and month and date. I want to change this date field, to a jquery date picker 
in active admin.

How can I do this customization in active admin? can someone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: I think you can check this link https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Combine-datetime-picker-with-activeadmin

Comment: Use this gem, which will help you a lot in active admin view `https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons`

Answer (score 0):

As written in the documentation here: https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html#datepicker
you can use JQuery datepicker in you custom views.
In your example I would use it like that:

```
form title: 'User details' do |f|
f.input :dob, as: :datepicker,
      datepicker_options: { show_week: true, first_day: 1 ,
                           dateFormat: 'DD, dd-MM-yy',setDate: '0'}
end
```